# Как установить layout в JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, layout

Закончил изучать swing и решил попробовать javaFx, буквально с самого начала у меня появилась проблема. 
Как можно установить layout в JavaFX? 
(на данный момент fxml разметку не знаю, если можно - без нее, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout задается использованием соответствующего наследника класса javafx.scene.layout.Pane как "контейнера". В пакете javafx.scene.layout.* можно посмотреть различные реализации, например, VBox, HBox, BorderPane.

Пример hello-world без использования FXML.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane root = new HBox(); // или VBox, StackPane
    // добавл. метки на панель
    root.getChildren().add(new Label("Hello"));
    root.getChildren().add(new Label("World"));
    // сцена
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: @Ruslan_P. Не подскажите, как это реализовать? Родитель моего приложения Application

Comment: Обновил ответ, дополнил простейшим примером.

Answer (score 1):

> на данный момент fxml разметку не знаю, если можно - без нее, пожалуйста

Альтернативой ручной настройки интерфейса путем редактирования fxml-файла является визуальный редактор – JavaFX Scene Builder.